# Closing JDBC connection when statement executing

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Recently I encountered the problem of having active sessions in the Oracle database after the Tomcat stopped. I decided to reproduce this situation and try to find a solution. Test code:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

@Slf4j
public class ClosingActiveOracleSession {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...", "username", "password");
        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                statement.execute("BEGIN\n"
                        + "  LOOP\n"
                        + "    dbms_lock.sleep(5);\n"
                        + "  END LOOP;\n"
                        + "END;");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("PL/SQL execution error", e);
            }
        }).start();
        log.info("[main] will sleep");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        log.info("[main] awoke");
        statement.cancel();
        log.info("statement canceled");
        statement.close();
        log.info("statement closed");
        connection.close();
        log.info("[main] connection closed");
    }
}
```

I get a message that the statement has been canceled, but message about its close does not occur. I suspect that the closing statement blocked by mutex (connection). Session in Oracle database still alive.

To check that this query can be canceled I ran this PL/SQL block in PL/SQL Developer and clicked on the "Break" button:

```
BEGIN
  LOOP
    dbms_lock.sleep(5);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

After some time I have ORA-01013 what does execution of PL/SQL block cancelled. The status of the session in Oracle database became inactive.

Does anybody know what is wrong with Oracle JDBC Driver?
Oracle driver version: ojdbc7-12.1.0.2
Oracle database version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

But this code works fine:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

@Slf4j
public class ClosingActiveOracleSession {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...", "username", "password");
        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_condition = 21332112");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Processing ResultSet failed", e);
            }
        }).start();
        log.info("[main] will sleep");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        log.info("[main] awoke");
        statement.cancel();
        log.info("statement cancelled");
        statement.close();
        log.info("statement closed");
        connection.close();
        log.info("[main] connection closed");
    }
}
```

When statement canceled I gotted:
java.sql.SQLException: Closed result set: next
and
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet
Thanks for help.
p.s.: sorry for my English

Comment: Do you see every debug message in log file ?

Comment: Only statement cancelled

Comment: I think that I need to register a bug in Oracle. Does anyone know how to do this?